# How to make a Barcode scanner in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I would like to create a barcode scanner in React Native with typescript; however, there are no libraries or anything that I can use.
I am not using EXPO.

Comment: Why are there no libraries?

Comment: Which library can I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new camera library which is https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/
and create QrCodeScanner using their frame processor : https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-code-scanner

Comment: Thanks! 
I am getting this error when I try to follow that, I think it is related to reanimated.
Task :react-native-vision-camera:buildCMakeDebug FAILED

React Native: 0.68.2
Reanimated: ^2.11.0
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.14.1"
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"

Comment: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1083 maybe can try this refference